# Equivalent idiom for "When it rains in [a place], it drips in [another place]"

Tags: idioms

In Dutch we have an expression

> *Als het regent in Parijs druppelt het in Brussel*.
> When it rains in Paris it drips in Brussels.

meaning that (political) events in Paris affect Belgian politics.

Is there an idiom in English with the same meaning? I couldn't find anything like "When it rains in...", so I expect the literal translation is out.

Comment: Why do Dutch people say that about Belgium and not about *Nederland*? And I would expect it be the other way round now – when it rains in Brussels it drips in Paris!

Comment: As an American, I had never heard that expression before, but the direct English translation sounds natural enough! I think people would understand it.

Comment: @WeatherVane when it rains in Brussels the EU moves its HQ to Paris? (-:

Comment: I've heard the expression "when it's rainy in *X*, it's dry in *Y*" (for regionally relevant locations of X and Y).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This isn't exactly the same, because in this expression it would pour in Brussels, not drip.

> **When the US sneezes, Canada catches a cold.**

[Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sneezes) has this as

> When (something) sneezes, (something else) catches a cold.
>
> When a person, group, or entity has a problem or experiences a negative situation, a related person, group, or entity will consequently have a worse problem or will experience a more negative situation.

Comment: I suppose the "Canada" version is natural enough (as a Brit, I'm perfectly familiar *When America sneezes, Britain catches a cold*). But by far the most common version is *When America sneezes, the **whole / rest of the world** catches a cold*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the version I posted is common enough. I thought "US / Canada" was a pairing more similar to "France / Belgium".

Comment: This idiom is derived from a Prince Metternich (1773–1859) saying : *When France sneezes, the rest of Europe catches cold*.

Comment: @Graffito so the OP's Dutch version seems to be close to the original.

Comment: Except that catching a cold is always a negative consequence, whereas IMO in the Dutch expression neither cause nor consequence have to be negative

Answer (score 8):

The situation is an example of the **ripple effect**.

> *ripple effect*: a situation in which one event produces effects which spread and produce further effects

[[Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ripple-effect)]

> - *Troubles in one corner, such as mortgages, have profound ripple effects on investments which seem far removed.*

[[Cambridge Business English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ripple-effect)]

> - *The Brexit vote is sure to have a ripple effect throughout Europe and beyond as nations struggle to figure out what the decision means
>   for their economic and political relationships with the UK.*

[[Colin Daileda; 'Mashable'; June 2016](https://mashable.com/article/world-leaders-react-to-brexit)

Again, this is not an exact match, the metaphor being usable in various developing situations, the effects not always undesirable.